# Graphing Profiler for Java?

Tags: java, clojure, jvm, profiling

I'm looking for a profiler for the JVM similar to Python's "run snake run".  The feature I'm missing the most is the "square map" visualization showing which methods are taking the most time to run.

http://www.vrplumber.com/programming/runsnakerun/screenshot-2.0.png

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If you look in the JDK_HOME/bin directory you will find jvisualvm and jconsole both of which help in profiling.

There is an [Eclipse Plug-in called TPTP](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/) that I've used before that worked pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

jProfiler with it's HotSpot CPU profiling to find bottlenecks... not a square map but with the same information: http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

[VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) can do [something like that](http://profiler.netbeans.org/blog/images/visualvm_12_cpusnap.png), albeit not in that "square map" format.